# possible to run sql query without any user action?

Tags: php, mysql, server

I want to know if it possible to run sql query when the other server send data to my server with post method. there is no user action. it direct send data from server to server.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "test";
    $password = "test123";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $selected = mysql_select_db("test",$conn)  or die("Could not select examples");


    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tablename`.`test` (`id`, `startdate`, `enddate`) VALUES (NULL, '2016-09-08', '2016-09-09');";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

**It is possible to run query without any user action?** Thanks.

Comment: @Andurit Hello bro. I just ask it is possible or not. it not deal with frontend. check my tag key words. php,sql,server, it is not front end that you said.i think you miss understanding to me.

Comment: I belieave i did understand it correcly. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a backend - frontend way how to comunicate between client and server. I know it doesn't sound like what you want but it is.

**How does it work:**
Because backend get request from client and base on this request he do something (e.g. make SQL Select).

In your case your client will be another server. And request will not come from some `.js` but instead from another `.php` file. However it still works same way.

**Very basic example:**

This is server which send data

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/server.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

this is server which wait for request:

```
if(isset($_POST['postvar1'])) {
   $data = $_POST['postvar1'];
   // Here comes your logic..
}
```

Comment: hello bro,i don't know what link submit data to my server. Can you show me how can i combine with your example and my code. Thanks

Comment: it's simple from there, you just make sure that data has come and do what you want..

Comment: Then you have some other issue in your code but it;s not an issue of this topic

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run a query without a user doing anything. You also don't want to use `mysql_*`. You might want to look at `mysqli_*` functions, or PDO.